# Ehcache integration with Hibernate & Spring Exception: Second-level cache is not enabled for usage

Tags: spring, hibernate, ehcache, second-level-cache

I'm using Spring 3.1 with Hibernate 4. While using Ehcache with Hibernate, getting an error like this:

**Second-level cache is not enabled for usage [hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache | hibernate.cache.use_query_cache]**

Even I set second_level_cache true, I still get same error.
Here's my definitions, I'll be happy if someone can help me.

Thanks & regards,

T

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource"><ref local="dataSource"/></property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.tk.sample.ext4.model" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
    <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
        <prop key="current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">auto</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.auto_close_session">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</prop>
        <!-- c3p0 properties -->
        <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">2</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">50</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts">30</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.acquireIncrement">5</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.initialPoolSize">2</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.maxPoolSize">50</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.maxIdleTime">300</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.maxStatements">50</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.minPoolSize">2</prop>
        <!-- Ehcache properties -->
        <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_configuration_file_resource_path">/WEB-INF/ehcache.xml</prop>
        **<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>**
        <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
    </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

ehcache.xml

```
  <ehcache>
  <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/>
  <defaultCache
     maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000"
     eternal="false"
     timeToIdleSeconds="120"
     timeToLiveSeconds="120"
     overflowToDisk="true"
     maxEntriesLocalDisk="10000000"
     diskPersistent="false"
     diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
     memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"
  />
</ehcache>
```

Answer (score 4):

This is discussed in other threads too
Remove the following line

```
<prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">
```

add the following

```
<prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory</prop>
```

The  Hibernate 3 and Hibernate 4 will have different configuration.

Comment: 0 down vote
 

Ehcache web reference speak about this configuration and I saw this method at others threads and blogs, but curiously hibernate 4 reference don't speak about hibernate.cache.region.factory_class and they maintain the old property hibernate.cache.provider_class