# Second level cache configuration using Infinispan and Hibernate in Jboss 7.1.1

Tags: hibernate, jboss7.x, infinispan

I am using Jboss 7.1.1 and Hibernate. I want to configure second level caching on single node.

### `standalone.xml`

```
<caches>
<cache name="simple" aliases="NoPassivationCache"/>
<cache name="passivating" passivation-store-ref="file" aliases="SimpleStatefulCache"/>
</caches>
<passivation-stores>
<file-passivation-store name="file"/>
</passivation-stores>
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:1.2" default-cache-container="hibernate">
<cache-container name="hibernate" default-cache="local-query"> 
<local-cache name="entity">
<transaction mode="NON_XA"/>
<eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
<expiration max-idle="100000"/>
</local-cache>
<local-cache name="local-query">
<transaction mode="NONE"/>
<eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
<expiration max-idle="100000"/>
<local-cache>
<local-cache name="timestamps">
<transaction mode="NONE"/>
<eviction strategy="NONE"/>
</local-cache>
</cache-container>
</subsystem>
```

And, hibernate properties are like this:

```
<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
<prop     key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.JndiInfinispanRegionFactory</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.cache.infinispan.cachemanager">java:CacheManager/entity</prop>
```

When I am deploying my application, following exception is coming:

```
17:20:16,949 INFO  [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory] (MSC service thread 1-2) Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
17:20:16,951 INFO  [org.hibernate.cache.UpdateTimestampsCache] (MSC service thread 1-2) starting update timestamps cache at region: org.hibernate.cache.UpdateTimestampsCache
17:20:16,952 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] (MSC service thread 1-2) Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@8deb1e: defining beans [mvcContentNegotiationManager,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0
...
```

Caused by `org.hibernate.cache.NoCachingEnabledException`. Second-level cache is not enabled for usage `[hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache | hibernate.cache.use_query_cache]`.

Any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

Please check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11206125/ehcache-integration-with-hibernate-spring-exception-second-level-cache-is-not) for the exception you are getting 
(org.hibernate.cache.NoCachingEnabledException)